# How to handle cancellation in Controller actions in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cancellation-token

I am developing a Web API with Asp.Net Core.

I am trying to figure out the best way to handle cancellation on the server side.

I normally have a service layer and implement a try-catch block in the service.

In this article [here](https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/) it is suggested to implement a Controller Action filter which will catch all the OperationCanceledExceptions from the services and return status code 400.

```
public class OperationCancelledExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public OperationCancelledExceptionFilter(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<OperationCancelledExceptionFilter>();
    }
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if(context.Exception is OperationCanceledException)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Request was cancelled");
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(400);
        }
    }
}
```

This means I will not catch this exception in the service layer, but let it reach the controller actions.

Is this the best approach you could think of? Do you have a better approach to suggest?

Comment: What would you do if you would catch that exception inside the service layer?

Comment: Well, in most cases I guess I would just return some error code and a standard message like "Operation cancelled". But in some cases I guess I could put some custom behaviour like also returning the data collected before the cancellation ... I just want to know if someone has a better suggestion from their practice.

Comment: You can still do that. If you don't want to handle it just convert it to error response then let it bubble up and let the appropriate filter / middleware handle it. If you want to handle it then capture it inside the service layer and return whatever value you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CancellationToken` is generally used for this job.

E.g ;

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CancelledTaskBugWorkaroundMessageHandler());

class CancelledTaskBugWorkaroundMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // Try to suppress response content when the cancellation token has fired; ASP.NET will log to the Application event log if there's content in this case.
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Or ;

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    try
    {
        await next();
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
    }
});
```

I hope that will be useful.

Comment: Thank you, @alierguc! I am currently writing the app, using ASP.NET CORE 6. This is how my Program class looks like. Could you let me know - where I should add this MessageHandler? https://github.com/MiBuena/BlazorAsyncMultithreading/blob/main/PopulationCensus/PopulationCensus/Server/Program.cs

Comment: maybe it can be passed on top of the constructor as a global variable

Comment: Your if statement is never going to be `true`.
That's because the contract regarding cancellation is that you must throw OperationCanceledException if the operation was cancelled before it has finished.
So http message handler from `base` will throw when cancellation was requested, therefore your if statement will never be `false`.